# IE & Edge Selenium drivers unable to find element in drop-down list

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-iedriver, selenium-edgedriver

I'm trying to select an element from a drop-down menu.

On my page, the drop-down items are all spans and looks something like this:

```
<span class="dropdownlist" id="MyID">
    <span class>Option 1</span>
    <span class>Option 2</span>
    <span class>Option 3</span>
    <span class>Option 4</span>
```

Because the only identifier is the innerText (I don't want to use nth:childs). I have to use XPaths to match against which looks something like this (I escape the " marks as I'm using C#):

```
//*[@id=\"MyID\"]/span[text()=\"Option 1\"]
```

When I run this using the Chrome Driver it works perfectly fine. However, when I use the IEDriver or EdgeDriver neither of these can find the element in the list.

All my CSS selectors (and some none text driven XPaths) up until this point in my test work fine, it is simply the drop-down field that is causing my problems.

Im currently starting my IE Driver with no capabilities set, could there be an option there I should be using perhaps?

UPDATE: I've tried using a CssSelector and this returns with an error saying that the element in the list I'm trying to click is not displayed. Running a little assertion to check if the element is displayed before clicking it returns false.

UPDATE 2: I've trying running some Java Script from inside my code to assign an ID to the element and then trying to click it using that, but I'm getting the same error (again, this method works in chrome and the ID is getting assigned properly)

Here's a picture of the control:

[image]

Code involves first clicking the field which makes the drop list appear, then selecting the item from the list.

```
    dropDownField.Click();
    IWebElement listItemToSelect= 
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()=\"Bangkok\"]"));
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
                       TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()=\"Bangkok\"]")));
        listItemToSelect.Click();
```

Comment: Post your code trials and error message.

Comment: I've tried using an XPath which uses a number reference just in case there is a particular issue with matching on text but this still didnt work:

//*[@id=\"MyID\"]/span[3]

Comment: Those spans are loaded in the page from the start or do they get added later by javascript? Are those spans hidden when you search for them?

Comment: Do a debug for IE then, inspect manually first to see if any difference for the selector, then check the root of the issue, if is loading or other cause and last see is there are any logged issues of IEDriver.

Comment: @rene The spans are visible even when the drop down list is not displayed on screen

Comment: I've just tried using an CssSelector which points to one of the list items using nth-child and I get the following error:

OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not displayed

Again however, this works fine in the chrome driver

Comment: Just ran an assertion testing if the element is "displayed" before attempting to click it and it returns false. Is there a way to "force" the element to display first before I click it? Again, this works fine in chrome and I've had no problem clicking the list item there

Comment: You might need to scroll it into view.

Comment: @rene I thought about that but the option I'm trying to select is at the top of the list and is visible on screen at the point it fails to find it

Comment: You have to run `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()=\"Bangkok\"]")));` **before** you do the `driver.FindElement` call.

Comment: @rene Just tried this and it does the same, timeout whilst waiting for ElementToBeClickable

Comment: Is that dropdown a [select2](https://select2.org/) driven drop down?

Comment: I'll just asking some devs now. Could this potentially be an issue if so?

Comment: I've just done some tests and the Span box that 'contains' the list of elements IEDriver can see. It shows it as both visible and enabled

Comment: So, I've sent a click to the container element and it selects an option from the list! However, it "Barcelona" which I assume is the centre of the visible element and just so happens to hit the Barcelona element. Feels like I'm getting a bit closer